# How to create a dynamic select form with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

No Jquery, just plain XMLHttpRequest.

So the flow is a pretty intuitive one. User has a profile and can change his selection of that form whenever he wants. It's a multiple selection. The data is stored in a database on the server of course.

I want to sync the change from the db info with what the user chooses on the go. I've looked around and it seems that just about everyone has had trouble with this and since I can't say I've figure it out after quite a few tries, I'd love some help. It seems that there's some problems with even what event to work with.

My failed attempt goes like this:

```
function checkSelect(selection)
{
params = "selected=" + selection.selected
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("POST", "checkdbOpts.php", true)
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
        if (this.status == 200)
            if (this.responseText != null)
                O('cat').innerHTML = this.responseText
}
request.send(params)
}
```

ajaxRequest is just a function that wraps the cross-browser instantiation of a XMLHttpRequest object.

```
<select id="cat" name="select[]"  multiple="multiple" onClick >
<option value="Opt1" onClick="checkSelect(this.selectedIndex)"> Value1</option>
<option value="Opt2" onClick="checkSelect(this.selectedIndex)"> Value2</option>
<option value="Opt3" onClick="checkSelect(this.selectedIndex)"> Value3</option>
<option value="Opt4" onClick="checkSelect(this.selectedIndex)"> Value4</option></select>
```

The .php file outputs a select tag with the selected attribute enabled according to the database info.

Any ideas on how to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
<select id='cat' onchange='checkSelect(this)'>  
   <option value='opt1'>Value1</option>  
   <option value='opt2'>Value2</option>  
   ...  
</select>
```

and the function:

```
function checkSelect(field)
    {
    params = "selected=" + field.options[field.selectedIndex].value
    ...
```

Comment: just to make sure, how would the output echoed by the php look like?

Comment: "selected=opt1" if you select the first option. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if it's that pair or just a full html tag...I've seen some confusing examples

Comment: It's just the string you build. I'd leave out "selected=" and just send the value of the selected option..

Comment: I still can't get it to work. My php is echoing "selected=option" and I've removed the quoted string in params. What is a way to debug this?

Comment: In the browser use "Live HTTP headers" to see exactly whats comming and going. In PHP echo (or write to a file) everything in the $_POST array.

Comment: What am I on the look for? The add-on tells me that it sees when I make the first selection and shows me the string but then it gives me a block that starts with HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: That it can't find checkdbOpts.php ?

Comment: Which is a shocker since those files are in the same directory

Comment: Fixed it. Didn't know it looks at it from the root.

Comment: last question before I accept your answer but do you have any idea on why there is nothing in my $_POST array when I change something on my form? is it a matter of not passing the right thing to that request or could it be something else? (I've tried a couple of different ways already).

Comment: I'd need to see the PHP. Maybe in another question.. But you need to be more specific when asking : )

Comment: I got it figured it out. Thanks a lot.